# Combine 2 Named Ranges in Excel - Not Using VBA

Tags: excel, range, named

Does anyone know if it is possible to combine two named ranges from different tabs in excel in to one master named range? I would prefer not to use VBA in this instance. I've had a look through the forums and have been unable to find a solution. Basically I have two different columns from two different reports which both contain ID numbers. I have created named ranges for both but am unable to combine. I've tried using Name Manager but have been unsuccessful.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? What is your intention when you combine the ranges?

Comment: just use two index functions with 1 or 2 iferror.

Comment: What do you want to do after combining two named ranges? Do you want to display data from two named range in a single column?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified in my post. I want to combine the two named ranges so that all the Id's are available under one named range. From there I am attempting to extract the unique id's. As multiple users will be using the template I'm attempting to automate the process for future use.

Comment: @jeeped -> thanks for the point in the right direction, managed to get the formula working using two different indexes. Thanks for the feedback everyone