# Data validation list based on combination of two dynamic lists

Tags: excel

I have a table where I want users to fill values off a list using data validation. The content of the validation list should be based on values entered in two other tables which are defined as dynamic named ranges (say list1 and list2). I need my validation list (say listAll) to update automatically whenever values are changed or added in list1 or list2.
For example:
[image]
I could easily achieve this with a macro triggered by changes in list1 or list2, but in this particular case using VBA is not allowed.
I can define a named range which simply REFERS TO: `=list1, list2`. This does indeed create a virtual combination of the lists but only usable in functions like `count` or `sum`. Using the combined list in data validation results in an error message:

> The list source must be a delimited list, or a reference to single row
> or column.

From similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926180/combine-named-range-with-other-options-in-one-data-validation-list) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394134/combine-2-named-ranges-in-excel-not-using-vba) and [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/combining-named-ranges-into-one-master-range-for-validation.23135/) and [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-combine-two-dynamic-named-ranges-named-formulas.817846/) It seems that previously there was no solution for this (without VBA), but I thought that it might be solvable with newer excel functions.
I have found a solution which I will post below, but it is cumbersome and I'm hoping someone can come up with something simpler and more elegant.

Comment: Use a third range (helping range) that will merge that two list using formula and then use that 3rd range as validation list.

Comment: @Harun24hr that is sort of what I did in my solution, the question is if you have a simpler way to merge the two lists in a third range while still accounting for the two original lists being dynamic and with varying lengths, plus of course not getting a bunch of blank cells in the merged list.

Comment: I think `TEXTJOIN()` and `FILTERXML()` can merger two different list into one easily.

Comment: @Harun24hr, `TEXTJOIN` may be unavailable. For example, I don't have such a function on my PC.

Comment: @ENIAC are you on MAC. `FILTERXML()` is not available on MAC excel.

Comment: @Harun24hr, no, I'm on Windows.

Comment: I actually have TEXTJOIN on windows (excel 365) but can't seem to make it do the trick (result is not accepted for data validation)

Comment: @eli-k You can't use these dynamic formula directly to data validation list. You have to use in a cell first then refer that cell with hash `#` operator. Suppose you put formula to `B1` cell then use `=B1#` in data validation list.

Comment: @ENIAC `FILTERXML()` is available to Excel-2013 and later for windows.

Comment: @Harun24hr, yes, I have `FILTERXML` function but I don't use it (even don't know how to use it). Thus, I've provided my own solution below.

Comment: @ENIAC `FILTERXML()` is a excellent formula. Read this post by JvdV to learn about FILTERXML. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/5514747

Comment: @Harun24hr, I've skimmed through it and it says that the strings should be in valid `XML` format, which I don't plan to learn for now. Anyway, thank you for sharing that link!

Comment: Do you have VSTACK? https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vstack-function

Comment: VSTACK looks like it's made exactly for my needs, but won't be available for me or my users for a while...

Comment: @Harun24hr, I haven't found a way to get data validation to work with the two lists using TEXTJOIN(), I would really appreciate it if you could post a solution with a description of what you have in mind.

Comment: @eli-k can you show some of dummy data with location of cells in sheet?

Comment: @Harun24hr see my edit with examle

Comment: @eli-k Please see my answer and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below formula to merger two or many list into one using `FILTERXML()` and `TEXTJOIN()` formula.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,A2:A20,B2:B20)&"</s></t>","//s")
```

Then use `#` operator to refer that dynamic range into data validation list like `=D2#`. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: `#` doesn't work for me. `Excel` throws me an error. How do you make it work?

Comment: `#` operator will work only on Microsoft 365. Not earlier versions of excel.

Comment: It works perfectly! I see that I can also use range names just as effectively. Pretty funny to go as far as translating it all to XML and retranslate back, and still a perfect one step solution... Thanks!

Comment: @eli-k If you are interested to know more about `FILTERXML()` then can read https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/5514747

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I use an auxiliary range which combines user-defined lists. As, I don't have `FILTER` function in my `Excel`, I use a number of formulas to get the combined list:

1. Combine both **maximum** possible length lists into one (column `F`).
2. Determine a sequence number of user input values (column `E`).
3. Number **all** rows in possible maximal list (column `H`).
4. Check which sequence numbers exist (column `I`).
5. Create a combined list (column `J`).
6. Finally, create a named range.

[image: Named Range]
[image: Formulas]

[image: demonstration]

Comment: Great solution without relying on advanced functions! ++1

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I found – in three steps (did I say cumbersome?):

Step 1:
I call each of the lists, both in one column (`D` in example), one well below the other – to make sure the top one has enough place to "evolve".

Step 2:
I use the filter function on the original column to have the two lists appear in a column stacked on top of each-other:
`=FILTER(D:D,D:D<>"")`
I tried entering this as the definition of a new name, but it is unusable for a data validation list ("evaluates to an error"). Therefore –

Step 3:
EDIT - following excellent improvement suggested by @Harun24hr:
I can now refer to the cell from step 2 directly in the data validation window, like this: `=$F&1#`.

[image]

Alternatively I can create a new name with the same reference, which I can use in data validation or for other uses. The new name is dynamically based on list1 and list2.

Comment: You no need `=OFFSET(Sheet2!$B$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!$B:$B),1)` Just use `Sheet2!B1#` in data validation list which will refer filtered data dynamically.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion - that's already a great improvement