# Excel: data validation based on data validation?

Tags: excel, validation, if-statement, excel-formula

I’m trying to build an If statement, based on a data validation list.

I want cell A1 on sheet 1 to pull from a list on sheet 2/column A, this I have done with a data validation list, BUT depending on what has been pulled I want cell A2 to display what is on sheet 2/column B.

Thanks in advance!

I have tried an IF statement =IF(sheet1!A1,sheet2!A1:A5,sheet2!B1:B5)

Obviously, that didn’t work… got a #VALUE! Error

I have also tried =Vlookup(A1,sheet2!A1:A5,MATCH(B1:B5,0),0)

And got #REF! Error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data validation list based on combination of two dynamic lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73017468/data-validation-list-based-on-combination-of-two-dynamic-lists)

Answer (score 0):

I was overcomplicating the vlookup.

In cell `B2` on sheet1:

```
=VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE)
```